# Passing String as POST parameter Retrofit payload

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm trying to pass a String to a POST retrofit method to my server.
This is my call:

```
Observable<MyOrder> addNoteOrder(@Header("Token1")String token1,
                                 @Header("Token2")String token1,
                                 @Path("orderId")long orderId,
                                 @Body String orderNote);
```

And I'm callin this way:

```
mRestApi.addNoteOrder("token1", "token2", "0", "001");
```

Debuggin with my server I'm having 500 error, because it tells me the error is in payload creation.

So,how can I send a String object as a payload to my server. This is the first time I do this.

Comment: What is your api ? Twice token1 at parameters ?

Answer (score 0):

The `@Path` replaces the parameter in the `POST` url with the string you pass to it. It should look something like

```
@POST("some/{orderId}")
Call<MyOrder> addNoteOrder(@Path("orderId") long orderId,
                           @Header("Token1") String token1,
                           @Header("Token2") String token1,
                           @Body String orderNote);
```

And call the service

```
Call<MyOrder> responseBodyCall = mRestApi.addNoteOrder(params);
responseBodyCall.clone().enqueue(new Callback<MyOrder>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<MyOrder> call, Response<MyOrder> response) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<MyOrder> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

Comment: I'm using retrofit 1.9

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your interface this way:

```
Observable<MyOrder> addNoteOrder(@HeaderMap HashMap<String, String> headers,
                                 @Path("orderId")long orderId,
                                 @Body String orderNote);
```

to call it with retrofit:

```
HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Token1",token1);
        headers.put("Token2", token2);
mRestApi.addNoteOrder(headers, 0, "001");
```

hope this will work.